# Android. MlKit how to correctly limit detection area?

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, android-camera2, android-camerax, google-mlkit

I'm using MLKit with cameraX for barcode scanning. I need to limit detection area. For this I create BarcodeGraphic and after get result from MLKit detector I'm trying to filter results and get first which inside my BarcodeGraphic. Here is my code (from sample app):

```
 val barcodeInCenter = results.firstOrNull { barcode ->
        val boundingBox = barcode.boundingBox ?: return@firstOrNull false
        val box = graphicOverlay.translateRect(boundingBox)
        box.contains(graphicOverlay.width / 2f, graphicOverlay.height / 2f)
    }
    graphicOverlay.clear()
    if (barcodeInCenter == null) {
        graphicOverlay.add(BarcodeGraphic(graphicOverlay))
    } else {
        graphicOverlay.clear()
        // handle result
    }
    graphicOverlay.invalidate()
```

However, this does not always work correctly. Sometimes, in order to get a result from the detector, I have to bring the camera too close to the barcode so that it goes beyond the scan area, and only in this case I get the scan result from the detector.

Can you please tell me what could be wrong with this code? Perhaps there is a better way? If anyone has come across this problem and managed to solve it, I would be very grateful for the help.

Comment: Shouldn't the condition in the "if" block be barcodeInCenter not null? You can also log out the results from the SDK to see if it's an issue from detection pipeline or your filtering logic.